# Prove that the spectral radius of F is 1

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, operator-theory, banach-spaces, spectral-theory

Here is the problem's input and output and I'll translate it as I have it in my homework and I'm willing to give you any information you need on the matter.

"Let $F \in B(l^2)$ given by
$F((x_n))_{n\in N} = (\frac{n+1}{n}x_n)_{n\in N}$ for any $(x_n)_{n \in N} \in l^2$. Prove that $\parallel F \parallel$ = 2 and that $S_p(F) = S(F) = a(F) = $ {$k \in K $}. Prove that the specral radius of F is 1. Thus, is possible that the spectral radius of a linear operator and continuous is less than the norm of the operator."

Where a(F) is the spectral radius.
Sp(F) is spectral point of F

If you know algorithm / book / other similar problem that might help me or you have an idea on how you would solve this, please say.
Also, if you need any information about the input of the problem, I'll be happy to assist you.

Comment: Something's not right. The spectral radius of your $F$ is $2$, since $e_1=(1,0,0,\ldots)$ is an eigenvector for $\lambda =2$.

Comment: Can you please describe me what you actually need, I do not work in a mathematical background, I do understand there is some confusion with the requirements, right?

Comment: Yes. You are asking for a proof of something that is false. I'm assuming there is some typo in what you wrote on what you were given, but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: I need to proove this: Prove that the spectre radius of F is 1. And I also need to proove this: Thus, is possible that the spectral radius of a linear operator and continuous is less than the norm of the operator, I think more specifically ,this part " is possible that the spectral radius of a linear operator and continuous is less than the norm of the operator". Is there way I can proove this?

Comment: There are examples, even in finite dimension, where the spectral radius is strictly less than the norm. Not in your example, though. You want to prove that the spectral radius of $F$ is 1, but the spectral radius of $F$ is 2.

Comment: Okay, so from what I see, this is divided into 3 subproblems: first proove this:  Prove that $\parallel F \parallel$ = 2 then this  $S_p(F) = S(F) = a(F) = $ {$k \in K $}. Finally, Prove that the specral radius of F is 1 and then this " Thus, is possible that the spectral radius of a linear operator and continuous is less than the norm of the operator.  I understand and I believe that $\parallel F \parallel = 2$ is different from F = 1, isn't it? So how should I approach this?